# Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError:unable to sign request without credentials set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a rails application and I am using dynamoDB as the database (using dynamoid). 
While I am running the tests, I get the following error:

`Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError:unable to sign request without credentials set`

Since tests are run in the local dynamoDB, I am a little confused over this error message. Is it that my tests are not running in local db and they are trying to access the remote db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the below configuration for local dynamodb. When you give the localhost endpoint, the dynamodb uses the endpoint directly rather than deriving the endpoint from region.

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret'),
  endpoint:'http://localhost:8000'
})
```

> The region is used to construct an SSL endpoint. If you need to
>   connect to a non-standard endpoint, you may specify the :endpoint
>   option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just missing setting 2 env vars, as documented in the official documentation: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration

After I set these, everything worked:

```
# Consumed by AWS Cognito under the hood. Required. A.k.a. client ID.
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Consumed by AWS Cognito under the hood. Required. A.k.a. client secret.
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```